# Algorithm for Clubbing together similar strings

Tags: string, algorithm

My api returns errors like so:

```
Server queue timeout 12
Server queue expired 23
```

They all basically mean the same thing. I want to club them all into one error that captures them all

I know I can just take the substring of first n characters, but I'm wondering if there's a general purpose algorithm?

Comment: *"one error that captures them all"*: and how would that message read for the example?